# edit function with builder completely not working - what is wrong?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit for the first time and was fine with the get, post and delete functions. I thought it would be easy to re-tool for the 'put' function, but when I dispatch from the front-end, it is getting reject and returning undefined. I literally have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Function on the backend first, which works when I use Postman.

```js
const updateOneMember =  asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {
  const member = await Members.findById(req.params.id)

  if(!member) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error("Member not found") 
  }
  const user = await Users.findById(req.user.id)
  if(!user) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error("User not found")
  }
  if(member.user.toString() !== user.id) {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error("User not authorized")
  }
  const updatedMember = await Members.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
  })
  res.status(200).json(updatedMember);
});
```

In Redux, I have in my member slice this code:

```js
export const memberSlice = createSlice({
  name: "members",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(addMember.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(addMember.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.members.push(action.payload);
      })
      .addCase(addMember.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getMembers.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getMembers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.members = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getMembers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(editMember.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(editMember.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.members = state.members.map((member) => {
          if (member._id === action.payload.id) {
              member.name = action.payload;
          }
      })
    })
      .addCase(editMember.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(deleteMember.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(deleteMember.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.members = state.members.filter( (member) => member._id !== action.payload.id )
      })
      .addCase(deleteMember.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

And in the member service file, I have for the edit  function

```js
const editMember = async (memberId, data, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:5000/api/me/family/${memberId}`, data, config);
  return response.data;
}
```

The add, get and delete functions all are working, but the edit isn't. It's returning undefined. I have double-checked the URL a million times (and again it works in Postman) and have changed around the state.members function on fulfilled a few ways. Everything is returning undefined. Any ideas? I am really stuck.

Comment: which http status the response returns to you?

Comment: rejectedWithValue: false,
    requestStatus: 'rejected',
    aborted: false,
    condition: false
  },

Comment: did you try to send an invalid user to api `updateOneMember` from postman? it's working fine?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work with a missing token for example. I've clearly set up something in the redux toolkit wrong. I just don't know what...

Comment: I think that maybe what you are missing is to use [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) to handle the request state, but there's another thing with your api, you are throwing an error when the user or member is not found but are you handling this error somewhere?

Comment: Actually I ended up figuring it out. I didn't put the data and Id in curly brackets. Ugh, what a headache! Thanks for the time Yago!